Translation of Dynamic Data (e.g., User Names, Addresses) in Flutter
I am currently working on a Flutter application that requires localization for dynamic data such as user name and address typing. I used a translator package to implement the localization. However, translation results are not always the same and vary in quality.
Are there alternatives to translator packages for this?
Is there a way to provide a reference to the translation API to get a more accurate translation?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
